# Why my AWS DynamoDB usage is being forcasted to cross the Free Tier limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have 5 tables in same region. All of them are in Provisioned Capacity Mode with 5 RCUs and 5 WCUs and have Auto-Scaling disabled. From what i understand, This means that i have 25 RCUs and 25 WCUs in total. Now according Free-Tier, I am allowed to use 25 RCUs and 25 WCUs. But when i visit Free Tier page in Billing Management, It shows me that forecasted usage till end of month will be 119% of Allowed free tier limit (18,600).

What should i do to prevent it from going above the limit?

Comment: Why do you expect it will go over the limit if you have set it not to auto-scale? Estimates are not live metrics...Has it done so in the past because that would be bad business that you could likely easily get refunded for